# replace PHP Escape sequence characters from string

Tags: php

I have string of URL with encoded google poly line. It has some time characters which are as same as PHP Escape Sequence (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) such as \v and other too. When I call this URL to download image from remote server the URL string get's altered and does not work.

How to handle Escape Sequence to let php script download the image properly.

Below URL in DB:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=275x270&sensor=true&markers=-31.95099,115.86053&markers=-31.952055,115.865051&path=weight:4%7Ccolor:0x0000FF%7Cenc:tl_bEi_dbUVol@gTug@aG_j@qe@_Le]_ZtO_i@tLsm@xd@sPdTu\sZeOq_@nZy_@wDsTah@_Dyl@cEg_@uImf@mKqU{WgJaEwd@mIs_@y[k]k^g[qi@GaUy\_Eqj@qi@aB{g@uJwi@uBe_@sYk^c_@ef@uOci@|A_h@_M}h@}Hcg@{Oi`@k]kIeh@tQsg@lKwa@fKs]~Fse@vi@@v`@oIti@Dbc@fKza@aIrEe`@dh@hBvi@Q`[mOb^{Mpa@eYpP_k@Eah@e@an@xFwl@jBmn@Zaq@bAmp@nFap@gGon@_Iio@m@{p@nCgp@eE_p@~Hko@hBaq@jB}p@lYyXpe@mJv`@i\nc@}Wpg@_Obi@Dve@`S~d@bR~F~i@dVdd@|WpShJic@db@nKzGvo@ne@`Et^rXyE`o@mRhi@iCvp@oZrd@eJvo@lVdg@hKrn@cFzn@v[pMfh@\xCfYiX|Sf@~n@eNld@}V`]qNjZs`@hYwa@rQeXrUcNxf@}Ipn@lApp@rUzf@|h@rAvi@Ydi@mBvf@tQvb@rWbHzo@~Gjo@r]tb@vWlg@rXzd@eBbj@eTvi@uSzj@{Fdp@uJ~m@k\nc@i]fb@c]jb@o]~a@c^ra@ySfd@yQve@gZrUu\lLc`@x]aItm@fAxi@nHtl@pRjh@
```

Below URL out put from PHP:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=275x270&sensor=true&markers=-31.95099,115.86053&markers=-31.952055,115.865051&path=weight:4%7Ccolor:0x0000FF%7Cenc:tl_bEi_dbUVol@gTug@aG_j@qe@_Le]_ZtO_i@tLsm@xd@sPdTu\sZeOq_@nZy_@wDsTah@_Dyl@cEg_@uImf@mKqU{WgJaEwd@mIs_@y[k]k^g[qi@GaUy\_Eqj@qi@aB{g@uJwi@uBe_@sYk^c_@ef@uOci@|A_h@_M}h@}Hcg@{Oi`@k]kIeh@tQsg@lKwa@fKs]~Fse@vi@@v`@oIti@Dbc@fKza@aIrEe`@dh@hBvi@Q`[mOb^{Mpa@eYpP_k@Eah@e@an@xFwl@jBmn@Zaq@bAmp@nFap@gGon@_Iio@m@{p@nCgp@eE_p@~Hko@hBaq@jB}p@lYyXpe@mJv`@ic@}Wpg@_Obi@Dve@`S~d@bR~F~i@dVdd@|WpShJic@db@nKzGvo@ne@`Et^rXyE`o@mRhi@iCvp@oZrd@eJvo@lVdg@hKrn@cFzn@v[pMfh@%C3%8FYiX|Sf@~n@eNld@}V`]qNjZs`@hYwa@rQeXrUcNxf@}Ipn@lApp@rUzf@|h@rAvi@Ydi@mBvf@tQvb@rWbHzo@~Gjo@r]tb@vWlg@rXzd@eBbj@eTvi@uSzj@{Fdp@uJ~m@kc@i]fb@c]jb@o]~a@c^ra@ySfd@yQve@gZrUu\lLc`@x]aItm@fAxi@nHtl@pRjh@
```

The URL from DB show path properly, where as same url when out put from PHP does not show path at all. Also the length of url gets reduced when output from PHP.

thanks

Waqas

Comment: You escape escape sequences by escaping them, e.g. changing `\v` to `\\v`.... but do you really need to escape or urlencode?

Comment: the encoded string part in the URL has some characters which php script is eating up and URL is sent out in request to download image is then gets bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use good old base64encode to encode the url and before you store in the database, if you have access to that code. Uses 33% more space, but helps with escape headaches. [PHP - Base64 Encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)